# Tab-completion when running a python3 script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python3, tab-completion

In Ubuntu, I'd like to be able to use tab-completion when running python. For example, if I wanted to use vim to edit a file 'myscript.py3', I'd write 'vim my' and pressing tab would complete the filename given it's the only file starting with 'my-'. However, the same tab feature does not work when I want to run the script: I have to manually type out 'python3 myscript.py3'.

Any suggestions on how to activate tab completion for python3 command?

Comment: It should work...Is `python3` a regular command or is it an alias/function? (E.g., does `type python3` say `/usr/bin/python3`?) If `vim` works for completion, then other command-line commands should work the same; the package(s) that enable this are `bash-completion` , which can be customized, but from personal experience, that's not where you want to go

Comment: ps: one thing that would work in any case, if `python3 foo[tab]` doesn't work, is to run `python3 ./foo[tab]` since then you're being explicit that you want file completion, and not e.g. completion of command line options.

Comment: the issue is that your file extension is .py3 not .py, and file completion assumes a .py extension for a python script, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017714/python2-autocompletes-file-names-on-bash-shell-python3-does-not

Comment: yes, @michael it says /usr/bin/python3. Also, autocomplete with python3 command works with anything that does not have a .py3 extension.

Comment: However, writing python3 xxxxx.py works and should be fine as far as I'm concerned

Comment: all & all, this is probably then a duplicate of this question/answer (and I agree with this answer, which in summary says "`py3`" is probably not a good extension for python scripts in any case, as it's not terribly standard & probably will break other things as well, eg syntax highlighting or things like that) https://askubuntu.com/a/1017726/17060